# Is "complexification" a valid word?

Tags: is-it-a-word

I have searched and I know that it is used in mathematics, but can it be used in the context of a sentence? Like the way we do simplification of a sentence, so for this usage, can we say that we perform complexification of a sentence?

Comment: The verb ("complexifier") ans  the noun("complexification") are common in French language, meaning adding more complexity. If you look at [French to  English translation examples](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/complexification.html), you  will notice that, apart one exception,  the word  "complexification" is never found in English text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's in neither [Merriam Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complexification) nor [Cambridge Dictionary online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=Complexification).  But:

- neither resource offers a suitable antonym of "simplification," neither in the dictionary nor the thesaurus (I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader)
- traditional users might prefer "complication" to "complexification," but

  - "complication" is not typically used to denote a process
  - "complication" is not suitable for contexts where it is desirable to maintain a distinction between "the process of making complicated" and "the process of making complex."
- the suffixes "-ify" and "-ification" are fully productive in modern English, meaning that you can apply them to any adjective and English speakers will be able to figure out what you mean.

The last point is essentially decisive for determining that "complexification" is a valid word; the preceding points are offered to show that you might actually want to use it, because there might not be a simpler or more common word available to serve your purpose.  Do consider, though, that in some cases it will be better to choose a phrase comprising more familiar words, such as "the increase in complexity was unfortunate" or "their making it more complex caused confusion."

Comment: As you say, *the suffixes "-ify" and "-ification" are fully productive in modern English.* Everything else is really just window dressing (including whether the derived term appears in other texts, dictionaries or not).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I tried to convey that in the last paragraph; thanks for saying it more succinctly.  But the lack of suitable synonyms is not entirely insignificant. I was thinking of examples such as _redification_ and _quickification_. There are contexts where you might want to use these words, but the first that comes to mind is comedy. With _quickification_ one might prefer _acceleration, speeding up,_ or _enlivening,_ etc.), and for _redification_ "reddening." The lack of suitable alternatives for "complexification" argued in favor of its use, though I would still advise caution.

Comment: Sure - it makes a huge difference to *likelihood of actually being used* whether there's already a word with the relevant meaning. And since English in general abhors synonyms, if someone *did* use, say, "quickification", I suppose we'd be tempted to assign it some subtly different meaning than "acceleration" (if we assume it came from a "competent" speaker, rather than just a learner who didn't know what he was saying).